# $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(x^2 \times 2^x \times (\log 2)^2) - (2^x - 1)^2}{(2^x - 1)^2(x^2 \times \log 2)} = ?$

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(x^2 \times 2^x \times (\log 2)^2) - (2^x - 1)^2}{(2^x - 1)^2(x^2 \times \log 2)}$$

I tried this by using the Taylor series $2^x = 1 + x\log 2 + \frac{x^2}{2!}(\log2)^2 + \dots$.

I used the first three terms for evaluation, and I'm getting the limit to be $\frac{\log 2}4$ but WolframAlpha is saying the answer is $\frac{-\log 2}{12}$.

Should I use more terms? Is there anything wrong with my method? Or is this just a miscalculation on my part?

Answer (score 2):

By setting $x=\frac{z}{\log 2}$ we get the simplified limit:

$$ \log(2)\cdot \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{z^2 e^z-(e^z-1)^2}{(e^z-1)^2 z^2}=\log(2)\cdot\lim_{z\to 0}\left(\frac{e^z}{(e^z-1)^2}-\frac{1}{z^2}\right). $$
Since the Laurent series of $\frac{e^z}{(e^z-1)^2}$ in a neigbourhood of $z=0$ is given by:
$$ \frac{e^z}{(e^z-1)^2}=\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{12}+O(z^2) $$
by differentiation of a [a well-known power series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html), Wolfram Alpha is right.